# How to get encoding type of a .txt or .sql file

Tags: java, sql, text, encoding

Is there a possibility to get the encoding of a existing .txt file? for example: you know a customer needs a specific encoding and you want to automize the process of .sql-data delivery. then you read out the endcoding from a client config and compare it to the current encoding of the file to be delivered. if they differ you change the encoding. could not find a solution till now. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean UTF8 ect? If so as far as i've read it is very difficult to accurately detect the encoding of the document.

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`juniversalchardet` is one of the best available API for detecting the encoding type. Please checkout this [link](https://code.google.com/p/juniversalchardet/). You can go through the list of encoding types supported by it

Working Example from the site

```
import org.mozilla.universalchardet.UniversalDetector;

public class TestDetector {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
    byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
    String fileName = args[0];
    java.io.FileInputStream fis = new java.io.FileInputStream(fileName);

    // (1)
    UniversalDetector detector = new UniversalDetector(null);

    // (2)
    int nread;
    while ((nread = fis.read(buf)) > 0 && !detector.isDone()) {
      detector.handleData(buf, 0, nread);
    }
    // (3)
    detector.dataEnd();

    // (4)
    String encoding = detector.getDetectedCharset();
    if (encoding != null) {
      System.out.println("Detected encoding = " + encoding);
    } else {
      System.out.println("No encoding detected.");
    }

    // (5)
    detector.reset();
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Lets say you have a file with just one INSERT Statement. This also wont be able to give you a 100% correct value for the encoding type or am i wrong?

Comment: OK Problem solved. If encoding cant be detected its not necessary to change encoding. my mistake

Answer (score 2):

There is no explicit declaration of text encoding in files, but you can guess the encoding by analyzing specific byte sequences that are characteristic of a certain encoding.

[Chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) does exactly that and tries to guess. If it can't say for sure what the encoding is, it will give you a list with confidence values (e.g. "90% this is utf8"). The project includes both a Python module and a command line tool. For a Java version, see [JChardet](http://jchardet.sourceforge.net/).

My 2cents: if you just need a quick way to detect, the command line `chardet` tool is the way to go.